# How hard would it be to re-purpose a nexus imprint sensor for use with a pi?

Tags: pi-3, camera

I have a nexus imprint fingerprint sensor from my old nexus 5x (2016).
I was wondering if there is an easy(ish) way to use it with the raspberry pi for biometric auth? It's a really good reader so would like to use it if I can.

EDIT:
[image: Fingerprint sensor back]
[image: Fingerprint sensor front]

Comment: is it a hardware scanner or is it a software based scanner that uses a camera?

Comment: Hardware scanner. It's the generation before the fingerprint sensors in the pixel 3. reads a fingerprint in about 600 ms.

Comment: Would also probably need to build a hardware interface - will upload images.

Comment: @jsotola posted images